# How do I detect the presence of objects using VBA in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, vba, late-binding

I have an Access 2016 application that gets distributed to many users who are not sophisticated users. They usually have to install the MS Runtime for Access. Despite clear directions, too many users still find that the application will not open. It appears that early bound objects are not present on the system. With bound objects not present no code ever loads or runs, so it is not even possible to give a good error message.

I am now attempting to write a small program in which all the objects needed by the application are late bound, thus being able to say which modules are missing, if any. What I am finding though is that my method for detection is failing even when I KNOW the object is present. The code below is an example of one test for a required object. This test always fails and I cannot figure out why. I have about 7 of these. Three seem to work correctly, but the others do not. Is there some different way I should be coding the "CreateObject"?

```
Private Sub btnOffice_Click()
    'Office    FileDialog    MSO.DLL       Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
    Dim obj As Object

    On Error GoTo xyzzy
    Set obj = CreateObject("Office.FileDialog")
    lblOffice.Caption = "Office module present"
    Exit Sub
xyzzy:
    lblOffice.Caption = officeWarning
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: [error 429](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231060(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: What does 'fails' mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FileDialog-Property-8510B02D-E455-44A9-BF38-3787E6D5C8C1. Maybe `Set obj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)`

Comment: @SeanC I have been over that list. It does not seem to apply. All of the objects I am testing for are present and work in my main application, where they are early bound. Why would the CreateObject fail in this context?

Comment: Fails == it branches to xyzzy. I'll try the mso...

Comment: Is everyone on Office 16.0?

Comment: Adding (msoFileDialogFilePicker) did not help, but it was a good idea.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Office 16.0? Probably not, but I have it and it fails on my machines. An advantage of late binding is that it should load objects that are equivalent but from another generation.

Comment: I'm not sure you can necessarily use CreateObject on *any* type of object...  Can you list the one which work and the ones which don't?

Comment: @TimWilliams Works:    
    Set obj = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    Set obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Doesn't Work: 
    Set obj = CreateObject("DAO.Database")
    Set obj = CreateObject("Office.FileDialog")
    Set dict = CreateObject("stdole.Stdfont")
    Set dict = CreateObject("VBA.FileSystem")

Comment: Each test I am doing represents one "checked" reference in the main application. Some of these I am sure are standard Win modules, but surprisingly I have been unable to find any source that tells me what objects are standard in any version of Windows.

Comment: Wouldn't the references menu (given early-bound refs) already say which libraries are missing?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Perhaps, but I need something that will execute on a random system, not only with Access or VB installed. The test app will not run until the Access Runtime is installed, but that is a more containable problem.

Comment: Well you can't use `CreateObject` to create an instance of an object you wouldn't be able to `New` up with early-bound code anyway, so there's very little hope for that Office library test. Make a separate module that doesn't reference any other code, and write a macro that inspects the project references and warns about any `Reference` instance with `IsBroken` returning `True`. Yes that's early-bound and requires trusting the VBIDE API, but you'll get your missing references.

Comment: Remove the failing references and use late binding. Then to determine if the object is supported, check if the related interface is present in the registry in `HKCR\Interface`. Use Ole/COM Viewer (oleview.exe) to get the clsid of each interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to detect broken References. Here's a procedure to check for and report broken references:

```
Sub CheckReferences()
    Dim ref As Reference

    For Each ref In References
        If ref.IsBroken Then
            MsgBox "Broken reference detected: " & vbCrLf & ref.Name & vbCrLf & ref.FullPath, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Broken Reference"
        End If
    Next ref
End Sub
```

Comment: If a program cannot start when it has broken references, how can this code be executed?

Comment: Put another way, if there are broken references, does the program fail because references cannot be satisfied or the first time a broken reference is used?

Comment: I don't think that code works with late bindings (and when having problems with references, it's often a good idea to use late bindings to bind to any version of a specific object).

Comment: I used it in a startup sub before I tried to do anything else. Access can start up and call a sub procedure before hitting anything that requires a reference. And maybe you don't need to use late bindings if you can detect that something you're expecting is missing.

Comment: @JohnMo OK, this works fine in my Access program. I had to set up an AutoExec macro that calls an InitFunc() function that performs this check. At the end I then open my form that opens and creates everything else in my application. That way the check code runs before anything else. I am now looking for a way to encapsulate this code. I tried the free version of VB but It does not seem to support the COM. How can I code this so that it will run on any system? Do I need a copy of VB6? I assume a .accdr will not execute at all on a system without the Access Runtime installed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do next when you say you want to encapsulate the code. You will need the Access Runtime or a full installation of Access to run the application parts of your database. If your next step is to eliminate the Access interface and just keep the database part, you will have to develop a UI in another tool, like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the file dialog is not available as a separate COM object, and thus you can’t use CreateObject() to create such an instance.

However, if you plan to distribute your application without an office reference (and I think you safe to do so – even with runtime), then you can change the FileDialog code to late binding:

Eg this:

```
Dim f    As FileDialog
Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 
f.Show 
MsgBox "file choose was " & f.SelectedItems(1)
```

Becomes this:

```
Dim f    As Object 
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3) 
f.AllowMultiSelect = True 
f.Show 
MsgBox "file choosen was " & f.SelectedItems(1)
```

So in your case, the filedialog is not available as a separate COM object, but you can still as above shows adopt late binding anyway. However, in my experience, it IS safe to distribute the runtime with a office reference and thus at least for the office dialog you don't need late binding. For reliability, since in the case of FileDialog the late binding code is not a big deal, then I would continue distribution without the office reference for the FileDialog and use the above late binding.